# copying std::map with pointer as key

Tags: c++, class, object, copy, copy-constructor

If I have the following C++ class:

```
template <typename T>
class my_class {
 public:
 private:
  struct assessment {
    int mark;
    String grade;
  } std::map<T*, mark> class_map;
}
```

If I were doing a deep copy with a copy constructor, how would I ensure that the content of the pointers in the keys are copied over, while also making sure each key is matched to the same assessment struct as a value? Currently I've got:

```
my_class(my_class const& other) {
  typename std::map<T*, mark>::iterator it = other.class_map.begin();
  while (it != other.class_map.end()) {
    class_map[it->first] = Struct assessment { 70, "Credit" }
  }
}
```

From this, the exact same addresses will be stored in the key, but I'm not sure how to make it so that the keys point to different addresses, but still point to the same content. I know it seems weird to have the keys as pointers, but there's a specific reason in my assignment that I need to do so.

Comment: The provided code doesn't compile at all. e.g. `mark` is not a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new T objects by *new* and T's copy constructor. But keep in mind, that order in map will be lost in copied map.

```
my_class(my_class const& other) {
   auto it = other.class_map.begin();
   while (it != other.class_map.end()) {
      T* newKey = new T(*it->first);
      class_map[newKey] = it->second;
      ++it;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this a bunch by using a ranged-based for loop.

Comment: Original code looks like C++98, so let's be close to a compiler which author probably used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler I'm using is modern - do you mind showing how this would be done with more modern techniques?

Comment: The original code looks like a bunch of stuff that won't compile. The question itself is not marked with a specific language version (e.g. [tag:c++98]), so the assumption is to answer with the current version language (this is explained in the [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)).